# UILocalNotification when application is background or active

Tags: iphone, ios, timer, uilocalnotification

In my app, i have to give notification(text and sound) at custom time interval .i.e 1min, 2mins, 3mins upto 59mins either my app is in background or app is active. I am using local notification for this.

I have two problems here:

1. When i select any time from my date time picker, i got notification in only 1min. For Eg. when i select 5mins and start timer, notification fire in every 1min not in 5mins. How can i get notification in custom time interval and how can i repeat it till i stop timer switch.
2. I got text and sound both in background but when my app is active i got only text not sound. So how can i play sound when my app is active.

Please Suggest me some idea. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: post what you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Custom time intervel is not possible**
   You cannot set custom time intervel for the `UILocalNotification`, You can only use **NSCalendarUnits** for the repeatInterval such as `NSMinuteCalendarUnit`

   ```
     notification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit
   ```
2. If you app is in foreground(active), you need to provide custom alertView and sound. The system will call `applicationDidReceiveNotification` only. For that you can use `UIAlertView` and `AVAudioPlayer`

   ```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
   {

     UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    // checking the state of the application
     if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) 
      {
         // Application is running in the foreground
         // Showing alert
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:alertTitle message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitle, nil];
         [alert show];
         [alert release];

       //Playing sound
       NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],notification.soundName]];

       AVAudioPlayer *newAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
       self.audioPlayer = newAudioPlayer;
       self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
       [self.audioPlayer play];
       [newAudioPlayer release];
     }
   }  

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
     {
       [self.audioPlayer stop];
     }
   ```

Comment: Some code means?? code for playing sound and showing alert?. That should be within   didReceiveLocalNotification. not in applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: See my edited answer. You need to check the application state also since didReceiveLocalNotification will call in both cases wether the application is in foreground or not

Comment: I think you are using system sound for notification.  instead of `notification.soundName` use @"default.mp3".  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"default.mp3"]]; Dont forget to copy one mp3 file named default.mp3 to the main bundle

Comment: Yeppeee, it works... actually i am missing @"%@/%@". Thanks a lot. BTW Sound notification comes continuosly. So am i use cancelAllnotification ?

Comment: See in code  self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; this will repeat sound infinitely. You have to handle this on button click of alertView. Just stop the audio player. In iso6 i think you need to cancel notification manually, otherwise notification remains in the notification bar.. check that one also